# Is there a way to remove a rogue node from our hazelcast cluster?

Tags: hazelcast

We are currently running a hazelcast cluster using it to communicate information on a queue to be picked up by a single node in the cluster. We are vulnerable however to a "rogue" node that joins the cluster but without the right version of software to handle the request in a way that's proper.

Is there a way proactively remove rogue nodes of this nature in a way that prevents them from actively re-joining the cluster? I haven't been able to see a way from the documentation.

Comment: Change the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using default hazelcast xml. You better need to have a custom hazelcast xml with updated Group credentials.

Comment: I think implied in the question is that these nodes were good at one time but have been deprecated and shutdown but then rejoins the cluster potentially with an older version of the application software or not fully configured or operational. 

I suppose we can update the group credentials with every software push? I'll look into this capability.

Comment: Ok, in that case you were not shutting them properly. Shutdowns are needed to be graceful but if for any reason(like long GC or OOM) if the node goes unresponsive then you would have to forcefully kill those kind of nodes(kill -9 <PID>). We had faced the exact same issue of hung state nodes impacting the cluster. They not only try to rejoin but also opens connection to clients.

Comment: The question I have if it's possible to do that sort of thing programmatically?
 
I am exploring adding group credentials which will prevent a node not having the same version of software installed - using software version as the password - from joining the cluster. That should help.

However if a node is brought down partially but still holds onto the cluster, that's  problem too, but in that case, I'm not sure how we would recognize and deal with that in an automated fashion.

Comment: I don't think there is any programmatic way to do that as the node is already out of cluster when it goes unresponsive. You can find ways of automating it by using UNIX cronjobs with logic to scan the available nodes and expected nodes.

Comment: Thanks, although the node is in the cluster, it's just not running in a way our application would like it to. So, it's picking stuff off our queue and doing bad things with it.

I think the group credentials will probably get us to where we want to be.